# Streaming HTML sanitizer

Tags: html, xml, sanitization, stax, html-sanitizing

Is there any HTML sanitizer that support streaming in any language?

If the answer is no, is there a reason?

Is it impossible to do, using API's like StAX?

Or is it just because nobody tried to build one yet?

Comment: "HTML" and "streaming" is a confusing combination, for me. What do you actually want the sanitizer to do?

Comment: @keshlam to sanitize some large html content with low memory consumption. This means parsing the html in streaming and removing non-whitelisted node elements. I mean what do JSoup, NekoHTML or things like that but without loading all the content in memory.

Comment: I think NekoHTML can run in SAX mode; you could certainly build a streaming filter out of that.